# Django models issue

Tags: django

I have created a model in Django as shown below

```
class work(models.Model):
    Image = models.FileField()
    text = models.CharField(max_length=10000)
    sub_text = models.CharField(max_length=10000)
    color=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    opacity = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    link =models.CharField(max_length=10000)
    grid_column = models.CharField(max_length=10000,blank=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200,default=all)
    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.text)
```

and while am trying to add values to that models through admin panel it throws the below error
TypeError at /admin/mysite/work_dummy/add/
all() takes exactly one argument (0 given)

Can anyone help me to solve this

Comment: You set default of your category model as a built-in `all` function. What was your goal for this default?

Comment: Even if I remove the default all from the migration it is getting the same error

Comment: add complete traceback

Comment: add complete traceback ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`max_length` for `CharField` is `255` so whatever you put in `Model` will not effect that in `database`, If you want to add more than that use `TextField` and also default takes a `string` or `int`, but since you have use `all` variable and i cant see a definition of that, i assume that wrong

```
class work(models.Model):
    Image = models.FileField(upload_to='media',blank=True)
    text = models.TextField()
    sub_text = models.TextField()
    color=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    opacity = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    link =models.TextField()
    grid_column = models.TextField(blank=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200,default='all')
    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.text)
```

Comment: It is not at all true that the limit of charfield is 255. The only issue with the original code is the default.